# Combine 2 projects- Main iOS app and Watchkit pp

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I am creating a seperate `WatchKit` application for an existing iOS application. The `Watchkit` app and the main app are 2 different Xcode projects.The problem is that I have to integrate this `Watchkit` app into the main app. I have seen solutions which tell me to work using `Xcode Workspace`. But I am not sure whether both the parent app and the `watchkit` app should be created using workspace or just the `watchkit` app. My problem is that I cannot modify the main app as it is already in the App store.

Comment: In what ways you "combine" the 2 projects? Just manage it in same workspace? or share the same set of frameworks?

Comment: The main project is a seperate project. I have to add the Watchkit app targets to it. I have created another project which has all the watch app codes

Comment: If you are going to give support of watch app for your main iOS app then all you need to do is add a watch kit target in you main iOS app, it will  create an extension and watchkitapp  for you in your main iOS app. After that all u need to do is move files into it. Why did you create a separate project for watch kit? If it is supposed to be  extension of your main iOS app then what have you implement in iOS part of that project?

Answer (score 1):

This question contains a false premise. The only way to distribute a WatchOS app is by embedding it in its partner iOS application, as an additional target, with a paired WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension. This is true for both WatchKit 1 apps (which can only run on Apple Watches still running WatchOS 1) and WatchKit 2 apps.

There is no barrier to altering an existing app in the app store—you simply need to create a new build of the iOS app, with the additional targets in it, and then submit this to App Store review in the usual fashion.

Finally, if for some reason you do not have access to the source code of the original iPhone application, then it is not possible to release an Apple Watch app that will partner with the app.

Comment: But this configuration is useful in some cases. For example, when using Unity. Unity automatically creates the project for you. So i'd be useful to be able to just drag another project into the unity created project and have it working (as you said distributed through the same app). So the question remains, is it possible to have the WatchKit App part in a different project so that it works by dragging it into the unity created project?